# how to display line numbers of errors

Tags: racket

I'm hacking in Racket and I keep getting errors.

The default error handler shows a stack trace.  At the end of the stack trace, it shows the "top level" evaluation as "/path/to/file/my_module.rkt: [running body]"

How do I show the line number for the running body part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use DrRacket, it will highlight the error location in the source.  To get similar functionality in the racket REPL, see the [errortrace](http://docs.racket-lang.org/errortrace/) tool.

Comment: I just spent quite some time searching for something like this, until I stumbled on this answer. I think it would be very helpful if there was some direct reference to this tool somewhere in one of the first sections of the Guide and the Reference.

Comment: For the cmdline interpreter this mean doing `racket -il errortrace -l xrepl`. Then `,bt` will show the errortrace output

Comment: From the guide the call for just running a program without REPL: `racket -l errortrace -t code.rkt`